# Analyze tags similar tags

Tags: ds.algorithms, data-mining

I have a system for tagging articles. Each editor ads different tags to each piece of content. For example:

for A: George Washington, first president
for B: first president, Washington George
for C: George Bush, USA

Is there any way I can generate "possible similar tags". For example I need to suggest to the editor that "George Washington" and "Washington George" are similar and I should merge them.

Comment: This is called  [Conflation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflation_%28disambiguation%29), which is known problem with a lot of works about it. 

It extends to beyond identifying person by name.

Comment: Conflation seems to be more about text. I might have gave some bad examples. For example, i want to suggest that the following tags are similar: government, administration.